# Can I replace just the knob of this outside spigot to fix this leak?

Tags: leak

This spigot leaks from the place where the handle attaches. Would I be lucky enough to be able to just need to replace the handle? Or would I need to also replace that brass piece it's connected to? All I can tell you about the faucet itself is that it's an anti-siphon one.

[image]

Comment: I believe you mean frost proof, most spigot's are pro-siphoning, all it takes is a turn of their knob. For a normal spigot, a leak there would mean the packing needs to be replaced. Not sure if the same procedure applies for frost proof since their layout varies with the much longer valve stem.

Comment: @BMitch An anti-siphoning spigot prevents siphoning in the other direction. It prevents hose; or usually more commonly irrigation, water from contaminating the supply.

Comment: I learn a new term every day. I had only known the backflow preventers and vacuum breakers that tend to get added on to normal faucets.

Answer (score 1):

If you're lucky, with a frost proof fixture like this, you may be able to slightly tighten the nut that's holding in the packing or gasket behind the handle. You'll need to have two wrenches for this, one to hold the faucet in place, and a second to tighten the nut.

If this nut doesn't want to turn (don't force it, else you may damage it and then need to replace the entire faucet), then you'll need to replace the packing or gasket around the valve stem. It's a cheap repair, but requires the water is off to the fixture and that you are gentle to avoid damaging the soft metal.

- shutoff the water
- open the faucet to be sure it's turned off
- remove the handle (usually held in with a screw)
- remove the nut with two wrenches, one holding the faucet in place and a second to turn the nut
- remove the valve stem by unscrewing it and pulling it out
- get a replacement packing (looks like some black string you wrap around the stem a couple times) or gasket to match what's currently there
- reverse the above steps to reassemble the faucet

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation and how-to! I'll give it a try this weekend.